# Font size for exporting iOS UIView to svg

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, svg

Developing a drawing app on ipad. I am trying to export whatever I draw on canvas (overriding UIView drawRect). Everything works fine except for the text. The problem is with the font size.

I am creating the font using systemFontOfSize:size for drawing on the canvas
and while exporting, I am using using the same size with pt. For example if the size is 15 then in the exported svg, adding a style attribute of text tag as

style="font-size:15pt;"

The Apple documentation says that the systemFontOfSize takes fontSize in points. So whatever I draw on the canvas should be of same size to the size of text in svg (rendered by firefox, Inkscape)

But the size of the text rendered by svg seems to be bigger. I have other drawing on the canvas e.g a rectangle, the size of the text relative to rectangle is bigger in svg than that is displayed on ipad screen. I am also drawing rectangle using point unit on both UIView and svg.

Is there anything I am missing? I am using both places point unit, so DPI should not matter..

Comment: Bummer, no one answered :/ I am interested too

Comment: I am also working this type of work. can you please explain us what you have done and which classed you have used so we can research on it and complete it. if you can share any git repo that will be also good for me.

@x64